# PHP CLI, How to search for function names

Tags: php, command-line-interface

php how would I go about finding out names of functions, classes and methods on cli. something like `composer require` does for packages.

PS: I know I can just search net, but sometimes, I am working offline.

Comment: You need to be way more specific. Functions for what? All packages don't have any CLI-features and if they do, it can basically be implemented in a myriad of ways. If you can't search online, you basically need to read the code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson look at my edits.

Comment: And you should look at my comment. There isn't one way to do that. It all depends on the implementation.

Comment: I just want an interactive suggestion by php when I mistype a class/method or function name.

Comment: well REPLs claim to.And I originally got this idea when using one.

Comment: So.. you want use an IDE?

Comment: when start using repl every where, this is what happens. :-)

Comment: @Federkun IDE? not really. just trying things out on cli with psy